# Clarification about Realm's current user on react native

Tags: react-native, realm

I am asking this question to get some more information about how Realm's current user is handled in react native:

When I access Realm.Sync.User.current, is it persisted across app launches and device's restarts? From my tests the answer seems to be yes since that variable has the proper data after a login and even an app restart, but since I didn't found any exhaustive documentation, I just wanna know if are there some things to consider when using Realm.Sync.User.current, or if it is always available after a login.

Many thanks